# Way to improve MS PowerPoint Export image quality without editing registry?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365, export, dpi, tiff

I need to export high-quality (dpi = 300+) .tiff images from PowerPoint.
[Microsoft tells me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/powerpoint/change-export-slide-resolution) I can do so by editing the registry.

I do not have admin rights on my computer and so cannot edit the registry.

Is there any other way to accomplish this goal?

---

Update:

The approach recommended by [this alternative Microsoft community page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/in-powerpoint-save-as-picture-saves-images-in-low/15ae4a58-6065-4b9a-b23a-ecb22f3cbf2a) also did not work:

"*Open PowerPoint and click File > Options > Advanced > under Image Size and Quality, check the box
**Do not compress images** in file and select **High fidelity** in the Default resolution list.*"

Comment: Have you actually *tried* to change those registry settings? They are all in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` area which as far as I know should be editable as it is your own user and not the wider machine settings.

Comment: @Mokubai I have. My employer has some administrative access request system set-up that blocks me when I try to run `regedit`. No one responds to it -_-

Comment: I am afraid you could not do it without registry editings.

Comment: Use a different computer?

Comment: I believe it is sufficient to change the registry entry in the USER part of the registry -- which does not require admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps too late for your need, but might help other users. If you need to export a high quality image that is in your powerpoint:

1. In the file explorer rename your .pptx file to .zip
2. Open/extract the zip file.
3. The HQ original images should be somewhere
   in the media folder.

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the alternative method suggested in that link is nonsense. It addresses what happens to images that you insert INTO PowerPoint, and has no direct bearing on the resolution of images you export FROM PowerPoint.

Have a look here, though:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00052_Improve_PowerPoint-s_GIF-_BMP-_PNG-_JPG_export_resolution.htm

See the "Do it yourself with VBA" link on that page. There's a bit of VBA code that you can modify to get much higher resolution images than PPT will save by default.

Disclaimer: This is a site that I maintain.